# NodeJs/Express, MySQL - Retrieve array using array of another table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, backend

I have two tables: Tasks and Updates. The Tasks table contains `ToDo` items, while the Updates table contains updates on tasks sent by users. Updates are tied to tasks via a matching `taskId` value in each table. I have a set of queries that successfully pulls all the tasks matching the user's permissions (`familyId`) - what I need to do next is use the `taskId` column values pulled from the 2nd query resulting array to then complete a statement like

```
SELECT taskUpdate FROM updates WHERE taskId = ?
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this.

Here is what I currently have:

```
// Get all tasks
Task.getAll = (userId, result) => {
  sql.query(`SELECT familyid FROM users WHERE id = '${userId}'`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error selecting from USERS: ", err);
      return result(null, err);
    }
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE familyId = ?", res[0].familyid, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error selecting from TASKS: ", err);
        return result(null, res);
      }
      console.log("tasks: ", res);
      return result(null, res);
    })
  });
};
```

You can see in the second nested query that I retrieve all rows from "tasks" where `familyId` matches the result pulled from the first query. So I want to use the `taskId` column to now match to rows in the Updates table with the same `taskId` value. The trickiest thing for me is figuring out how to use the array from the 2nd query - I have a vague idea of using something like a foreach loop but have tinkered for a while with no luck.

ADDENDUM: By request, here is sample data:

```
TASKS table 
taskId col: 200, 201...
taskName col: Test01, Test02...

UPDATES table
updateId: 1, 2...
taskId: 200, 201...
taskUpdate: "Checked garage", "Need to go to store"...
```

...There are more columns in each but the only columns that really matter here are taskId in each and taskUpdate in Updates.

After pulling the tasks in "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE familyId = ?", we'll have an array of tasks. I need to use the taskId column values from that array and feed all resultant taskId values into "SELECT taskUpdate FROM updates WHERE taskId = ?" so that I can retrieve the taskUpdate values shown above.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: I added that information as you requested.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to join the two tables on familyid?